# How do i add a .png to JButton

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jbutton

I am working on a main menu for a program and i am finding it hard to apply a .png file to my JButton, this is where i have arrived

```
public class Menu extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Color b = new Color(0,89,255);
    Color t = new Color(255,0,0);
    Color bttn = new Color (255,255,0);


    final JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Main Menu");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(1000,750);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setBackground(b);


    JButton start = new JButton ("Start");
    start.setBounds(300, 300, 150, 75);
    start.setForeground(t);


    JButton exit = new JButton ("Exit");
    exit.setBounds(550, 300, 150, 75);
    exit.setBackground(bttn);
    exit.setForeground(t);
```

Pls leave any answer as i am trying to hurry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon("/path/to/image.png"));
```

is the way you would do what you want after you have created a `JButton`. If you want to add an image at the time of creating a `JButton` then you can use the appropriate constructor.

```
JButton myButton = new JButton("What The Heck?", new ImageIcon("/path/to/image.png"));
```

and please so not use a `null` layout. Use a `LayoutManager` instead.

Comment: Do i keep start.setBounds(300, 300, 150, 75);

Comment: It all depends on how you want to layout your `JComponents`. Sometimes you need a combination of `LayoutManager`s

Comment: `Do i keep start.setBounds(300, 300, 150, 75);`, No. You should NOT be using setBounds. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.